# Pie chart with linq

Tags: linq, charts

I am binding Microsoft Pie Chart with linq query but no chart appears screen remains blank
Here is my code

```
 adoentityEntities objSlTestEntities = new adoentityEntities();
                var query = from c in objSlTestEntities.tblcategories
                            join p in objSlTestEntities.tblproducts on c.CTID equals p.CTID
                            group c by new { c.CTID, p.Name } into er
                            select new { Title = er.Select(item => item.Title), no = er.Count(), er.Key.Name };

                SalesChart.DataSource = query;
                SalesChart.DataBind();
```

Comment: i have solved the prb i did not set x value member and y value member
it should be replaced by

   SalesChart.DataSource = query.ToList();
                SalesChart.Series[0].XValueMember = "Title";
                SalesChart.Series[0].YValueMembers = "no";
                SalesChart.DataBind();

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your own question and accept it... then people can up-vote it ;)